# Fetch returning null, but rowCount giving the correct number of rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

So I have this little PDO code right here:

```
$list=array();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM cal_project JOIN cal_customer ON cal_project.cust_id = cal_customer.cust_id" . $limit);
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $list[] = $row;
}
return $list
```

Which returns empty when I echo it to my app. Now, I also have this little snipbit:

```
$num_returns = $stmt->rowCount();
```

Which returns the proper number of rows every time. Any ideas what could be the cause of the issue? I know that the sql works on its own, both from row count and testing in phpMyAdmin

Edit:
So response calls to list keys, the function that the code above is held in:

```
$response['list'] = listKeys($request,$object->techID, $limit);
echo json_encode($response);
```

As I stated in a comment, this code works perfectly fine in PHP 5.4, but not in 5.5 and above

Edit 2: Added in declaration for $list to help subvert confusion and returned $list because I forgot to paste it in

Comment: Also, this works in PHP 5.4 but not any version above

Comment: What are you echoing? What is `count($list);`?

Comment: Where is $list defined ?

Comment: So I return list to another file, and I echo that. count($list) returns 2, as it should.

Comment: @MateoBarahona, at the beginning of the function this code is in

Comment: Does `$limit` have a space at the beginning? Is `$pdo` defined within your function?

Comment: Yes $limit does have a space at the beginning, and $pdo is defined in another file.

Comment: Defining `$pdo` in another file will not make it available to your function. You must either define it within the function or pass it as an argument. Although, I guess it must be defined, or `$stmt->rowCount()` wouldn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I wrote it like that. I meant to say that $pdo is defined by a call to a function in another file. Ex: if(!isset($pdo)){ $pdo->pdoConnect();}

Comment: It seems that there isn't quite enough of your code here to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is there a more comprehensive changelog from php 5.4 to 5.5 than the one provided at http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.changes.php